# using resizable function on div moves the other division to next line

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

I am very very new to javascript/Html/CSS and have to use it to add small functionality in one of the existing websites. I am planning to have a resizable division so that if we have a bigger image/drawing on the left side of division it can be resized. The right side of the division is text. 
I have used resizable() function and when I resize the first division the other division goes into a new line. I am not sure how to fix this. When the page loads, I need the background division to have 50% width and textfield to have 47.5%. But, on resizing background division - the textfield should auto resize it's width.

Edit: fixed the html typo issue.

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/yguw/t3e9xgbg/

Please suggest as to how I fix this problem.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>TEST</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/test.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/menu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#background").resizable();
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Code block start - NT -->
<div class="topbar">
 <div class="topbarleft">
  <div class="searchbarleft">
    <p>testing</p>
  </div>
  <div class="searchbarright">
    <input type="text" id="box" name="fname" size="50">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="topbarright">
  <div class="topbarleft">
  </div>
  <div class="topbarright">
    <a href='/test/r/signout' style='color:white;'>SignOut</a>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mainDiv">
<div id="background" class="background"></div>
<div id="textField" class="textField">
</div>
</div>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/testYG.js"></script> -->

</body>


<div class="mainDiv">
<div id="resizable" class="background" id="background"></div>
<div id="resizable" class="textField" id="textDivField">
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: This likely has nothing to do with the question... But, why do you have code outside of the `</html>` tag?

Comment: if you use flex(again !), it makes it easier https://jsfiddle.net/t3e9xgbg/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead float, you may use display: table or flex to draw a row.

```js
    $(function() {
      $("#background").resizable();
    });
```

```css
.mainDiv {
  height: relative;
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}

:root {
  background: 900px;
  position: relative;
}

#background {
  background-color: rgb(255, 200, 240);
  height: 50vh;
  width:50%;
  display:table-cell;
  margin: 0;
}

#textField {
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 200);
  display:table-cell;
  padding: 1%;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 

  <div class="topbar">
    <div class="topbarleft">
      <div class="searchbarleft">
        <p>testing</p>
      </div>
      <div class="searchbarright">
        <input type="text" id="box" name="fname" size="50">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="topbarright">
      <div class="topbarleft">
      </div>
      <div class="topbarright">
        <a href='/test/r/signout' style='color:white;'>SignOut</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mainDiv">
    <div id="background" class="background"></div>
    <div id="textField" class="textField">
    </div>
  </div>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#background").resizable();
});
```

```css
.mainDiv {
  height: relative;
  display: flex;
}
:root {
  background: 900px;
  position: relative;
}
#background {
  background-color: rgb(255, 200, 240);
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
}
#textField {
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 200);
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 1%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div class="topbar">
  <div class="topbarleft">
    <div class="searchbarleft">
      <p>testing</p>
    </div>
    <div class="searchbarright">
      <input type="text" id="box" name="fname" size="50">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="topbarright">
    <div class="topbarleft">
    </div>
    <div class="topbarright">
      <a href='/test/r/signout' style='color:white;'>SignOut</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div id="background" class="background"></div>
  <div id="textField" class="textField">
  </div>
</div>
```